# jquery star rating functinality how to use in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I want j query star rating functionality implementing in to the code igniter frame work.
If you have any working example please let me know or please help me how implement them.

the bellow site example not working
http://sumonbd.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/star-rating-using-jquery-and-codeigniter/

Comment: may i know wats the issue that u re facing... Elaborate your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the rating system tutorial using codeIgniter in this [reference](http://sankethpatel.com/blog/star-rating-using-jquery-and-codeigniter/) link with demo.

Comment: http://programmingcodezone.blogspot.in/2013/08/jquery-star-rating-functinality-how-to.html it is working fine

Comment: accept it as answer and upvote it. All the best. By the way are you a developer